# About the http request standard

Tags: http

```
GET http://stackoverflow.com/questions HTTP/1.1
Host: stackoverflow.com
```

Does the HTTP standard require that `GET` requests are fed with an absolute or relative address? What about when the request is in a proxy?

I ask this because I feel it's duplicate with the `Host` info.

Answer (score 5):

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
```

Is a valid request line. The full path is not necessary.

> 5.1.2 Request-URI
>
> The Request-URI is a Uniform Resource
>   Identifier (section 3.2) and
>   identifies the resource upon which to
>   apply the request.
>
> ```
>    Request-URI    = "*" | absoluteURI | abs_path | authority
> ```
>
> The four options for Request-URI are
>   dependent on the nature of the
>   request. The asterisk "*" means that
>   the request does not apply to a
>   particular resource, but to the server
>   itself, and is only allowed when the
>   method used does not necessarily apply
>   to a resource. One example would be
>
> ```
>    OPTIONS * HTTP/1.1
> ```
>
> The absoluteURI form is REQUIRED when
>   the request is being made to a proxy.
>   The proxy is requested to forward the
>   request or service it from a valid
>   cache, and return the response. Note
>   that the proxy MAY forward the request
>   on to another proxy or directly to the
>   server specified by the absoluteURI. In order
>   to avoid request loops, a proxy MUST
>   be able to recognize all of its server
>   names, including any aliases, local
>   variations, and the numeric IP
>   address. An example Request-Line would
>   be:
>
> ```
>    GET http://www.w3.org/pub/WWW/TheProject.html HTTP/1.1
> ```
>
> To allow for transition to
>   absoluteURIs in all requests in future
>   versions of HTTP, all HTTP/1.1 servers
>   MUST accept the absoluteURI form in
>   requests, even though HTTP/1.1 clients
>   will only generate them in requests to
>   proxies.

Comment: The Host header is required, however.

Comment: Yes, I meant to say 'request line' rather than 'request'. I've updated the answer.

Comment: which is standard practice,extract host name from absolute URI or using the host header?

Comment: @DriverBoy: Reading the above, if you are writing a proxy, then you should use the URI. However if you are writing an endpoint (HTTP server), then you should honour the `Host` header.

Comment: Minor quibble:  "The full path is not necessary" UNLESS the request is made to a proxy, in which case it is REQUIRED.

Answer (score 0):

You can consult the [HTTP RFC](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2616.html) for this.

> 3.2.1 General Syntax
>
> URIs in HTTP can be represented in absolute form or relative to some
>      known base URI [11], depending upon the context of their use.

Answer (score 0):

Host details are not required. Relative path is sufficient